# dot product not working

Tags: functions, matrix, dot

Im supposed to take the dot product of a function and itself. The matrix is a system of 4 equations defined to be :

```
L[x_, y_, z_, w_] :=
   {{4.0 x - 2 y + 3 z - 5 w},
    {3 x + 3 y + 3 z - 8 w  },
    {-6 x - y + 4 z + 3 w   },
    {-4 x + 2 y + 3 z + 5 w }}
```

I can't take `L[x,y,z,w].L[x,y,z,w]` because Dot::dotsh error. I was able to successfully take the dot product earlier today but for some reason, I can't anymore.

Comment: Is that really supposed to be a $4\times1$ matrix? If not, remove the inner braces: `L[x_, y_, z_, w_] := {4.0 x - 2 y + 3 z - 5 w, (* stuff *)}`

Comment: hi. If you do this, then the error goes way `r1=L0[x,y,z,w];
r1.Transpose[r1]`

Comment: Have you read the description of this error in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
L[x_, y_, z_, w_] := {4.0 x - 2 y + 3 z - 5 w, 
  3 x + 3 y + 3 z - 8 w, -6 x - y + 4 z + 3 w, -4 x + 2 y + 3 z + 5 w}
```

i.e. remove the multiple curly brackets.

So that you have output

```
In[71]:= Dot[L[x, y, z, w], L[x, y, z, w]]

Out[71]= (-5 w + 4. x - 2 y + 3 z)^2 + (5 w - 4 x + 2 y + 
   3 z)^2 + (-8 w + 3 x + 3 y + 3 z)^2 + (3 w - 6 x - y + 4 z)^2
```

Also check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it worked before is that you were using plain 1-dimensional lists.  `Dot` works well with 1D lists.  Your definition of `L` returns a 2-dimensional list (4 rows by 1 column), which does not work (natively) with `Dot` .

If you do not want to change the definition of `L`, you can calculate the dot product using

```
L[a, b, c, d][[All, 1]].L[w, x, y, z][[All, 1]]
```

or by using

```
Plus @@ Apply[Times, Transpose@{L[a, b, c, d], L[w, x, y, z]}, 2]
```

or what amounts to the same thing,

```
Total@Flatten[Transpose@L[a, b, c, d]*Transpose@L[w, x, y, z]]
```

If you want it both ways, you can define a new `L` that returns a 1-dimensional list.  Use the new one for calculations, since it works with `Dot`.  When you want need the old 4x1 form, simply wrap the new form with braces and take the transpose, like this: `Transpose[{new}]`.

Comment: I get your point, but it's a bit confusing to say that "Dot works with 1D lists". `Dot` works with arbitrary dimensional tensors, contracting the last index of the first tensor with the first index of the second tensor.  It's what we use for matrix products. One can't multiply a 4x1 matrix with a 4x1 matrix.

Comment: @Szabolcs  Many thanks for pointing that out.  It seems so obvious.  I would fix my answer, but what more could I say than is already in the documentation, or in your comment.   I agree the question is off topic.